# Retrieving cordova context results in: 'error: cannot find symbol variable cordova'

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to alter the files for the plugin `cordova-plugin-firebase` I am specifically trying to alter the file `FirebasePluginMessagingService.java` by adding the code below within the `onMessageReceived();`

```
Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, 13);
```

However, everytime I run this code I get:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable cordova
```

I think I have the necessary stuff imported:

```
package org.apache.cordova.firebase;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.graphics.Color;

import me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with

```
this.getApplicationContext()
```

That's how the context is got in the `FirebasePluginMessagingService.java` file at least.